# Disabling password authentication not working

Tags: ssh

On a Ubuntu 22.04 machine, I'm trying to disable password authentication. To achieve that, I have updated `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` from

```
...
# PasswordAuthentication yes
...
```

to

```
...
PasswordAuthentication no
...
```

And then restarted `sshd` with `sudo systemctl restart ssh`.

However, password authentication is still working.

Am I missing anything here?

On the machine, it's installed `OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022`.

Answer (score 0):

I would first check to see if you have an Include directory (or file) defined, such as:

```
/etc/sshd_config.d/
```

There's a chance there is an include file that is overriding /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Next, see what systemctl is doing. Look at `/etc/sysconfig/sshd` and `/etc/sysconfig/sshd-permitrootlogin` and maybe adjust those, as needed. Those are the path/filenames on RHEL 8, I think it's the same for Ubuntu 22.04.

I would also check the ssh client.  An ssh command-line option `-o PreferredAuthentications=password` might override the server preference.   Check to see if something similar exists in your client's `~/.ssh/config` file, or if using he server's client (to localhost), it may use /etc/ssh/ssh_config.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I missed it earlier or if it is new.
Now /etc/ssh has a directory **sshd_config.d**! The way I fixed it was settingPasswordAuthentication no in a conf file in that directory!

I thought sshd was used by RH and ubuntu used ssh (as in sudo systemctl restart ssh)!